# Using readahead in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, startup, cache

The article [BootProcessSpeedup on the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BootProcessSpeedup) lists a tip to speed up boot time. It says to install readahead and then `#touch /etc/readahead/profile-once`.

It seems like an outdated article, because when I try this, it gives an error saying there's no such file or directory (it's referring to readahead). I browsed to /etc/ and noticed that there is a folder called readahead.d, not readahead. What do I need to do? modify the command to include ".d"? Or not do anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get helpful info on an installed package, start by listing the files it contains:

```
dpkg -L readahead-fedora
```

(I think that is the name of the package you are using). You will see files

```
/usr/share/man/man8/readahead-collector.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/readahead.8.gz
```

which are *man pages*, so you can try `man 8 readahead` etc to get some info. (`man readahead` may get you a different man page). However, I looked in both man pages and didn't find much useful.  Looking at the other files in the package there is:

```
/usr/share/doc/readahead-fedora/README
```

which says "To manually trigger the collector on next boot use"

```
touch /.readahead_collect
```

So that seems like the answer in this case (though, honestly, a README like this may not always be uptodate, so beware).

Comment: Thanks for answering. After reading this I found the same command on the Debian forums listed for Squeeze. So I ran this command and rebooted, but noticed nothing at all during bootup. I remember reading that profiling would take a long time. Did it just take less time on my machine? I have no way of knowing if it worked. :(

Comment: It seems it only runs during the very early stages of boot. You should find files in `/etc/readahead.d/` listing files to load. I tried it on my raspberry pi and it wasnt useful. But I'm not sure it worked entirely, as it left `/.readahead_collect` which it is supposed to remove after a reboot.

Comment: Well, my .readahead_collect did get removed, so I think it worked. Didn't help much with boot time though.